# Symfony2 service param constructor error

Tags: php, symfony, fatal-error

I am using symfony2 and I use one service to notify my users based in some action sof the system. Well, It worked pretty fine in my local environment, now in production I am having some issues.

The service is dlecared on services.txt as:

```
mybundle.notify:
    class: NC8Digital\CRMBundle\Services\Notify
    arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @templating, @mailer ]
```

And the class is declared as

```
public function __construct(EntityManager $em, TimedTwigEngine $templating, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
```

And I am receiving this error:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 2 passed to NC8Digital\\CRMBundle\\Services\\Notify::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\\Bundle\\TwigBundle\\Debug\\TimedTwigEngine, instance of Symfony\\Bundle\\TwigBundle\\TwigEngine given, called in /mypath/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 367 and defined in /mypath/src/NC8Digital/CRMBundle/Services/Notify.php on line 43
```

First thing I tried was to change my constructor to solve the problem... got a 500 error on my browser, so I changed back.

Comment: What did you change in the constructor? TimedTwigEngine to TwigEngine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type-hint the second parameter with `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface`.

Comment: Thanks!!! just solved my problem! now I just will try to figure out why I had this diferrence on the two environments.